# Sum variables and process sign expressions in ConTeXt

Tags: context, calculations, environment-variables

I try to generate random exercises:

```
\setvariables[parametres][a=-4, b=2, c=4]


\starttext

Solve:
\startformula
\getvariable{parametres}{c} x + (\getvariable{parametres}{a}+2) x = 5
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

I want to generate this:

```
Solve:
4x-2x = 5
```

Note that I need to ConTeXt adds the value of `a` plus `2` and then calculate the sign of resulting sum: `+(-2)x` would be `-2x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such one-off things, you can also use `\luaexpr`.

```
\setvariables[parametres][a=-4, b=2, c=4]

\starttext

Solve:
\startformula
\getvariable{parametres}{c} x 
\luaexpr[+d]{\getvariable{parametres}{a}+2} x 
\luaexpr[+d]{\getvariable{b}+1} 
= 5
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

The optional argument `+d` is a lua `formatter` (see the cld-mkiv manual for full details). Think of it like `%+d` in `printf` in C and similar languages. The `+` specifies to always print the sign and `d` specifies that the argument is a decimal (integer).

But if you are generating a series of exercises, I'd just generate everything in Lua (using CLD: [ConTeXt Lua Documents](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf)).

Comment: So, there is no automatic way to lua simplifies `+a` if a is negative?

Comment: I get `[ctxlua]:1: unexpected symbol near '[` If I remove `\luaexpr[+d]` all is fine. I use MKIV. Without `[+d]` all is fine

Comment: @somenxavier I tested this in the latest LMTX. what is the version that you are using (output of `context --version`

Comment: This is the output: `context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.04
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2021.03.05 19:11
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2021.03.05 19:11`

Comment: what's the difference between `\luaexpr` and `\ctxlua` (which I see in many places here)

Answer (score 1):

ConTeX is based on TeX, so you can use TeX primitive approach:

```
\setvariables[parametres][a=-4, b=2, c=4]
\newcount\numA

\starttext

Solve:
\startformula
\numA=\numexpr \getvariable{parametres}{a} + 2 \relax
\ifnum\numA<0 \def\sign{-}\numA=-\numA \else\def\sign{+}\fi
\getvariable{parametres}{c} x \sign \the\numA x = 5
\stopformula
aha
\stoptext
```

Comment: I get this error ` Undefined control sequence

<recently read> \numA `

Comment: @somenxavier `\numA` is declared by `\newcount`, it is not undefined control sequence. I tested this with ConTeXt mkiv in TeXlive and there is no problem.

Comment: Mmm. I don't know what happened here